# Win32 ShellExecute and a UNC Path

Tags: vba, flash, powerpoint

I want to fire up a flash presentation inside Powerpoint 2007. I am calling the Win32 ShellExecute() routine. When I run this from a location whose path is a UNC path (\myserver\myfolder\sample.ppt) it does not work.

The ShellExecute routine expects 6 arguments, one of which is the path to run it from. I've tried to set this parameter to C:\ as well as using ActivePresentation.Path (which is a UNC path). Neither works.

Comment: Can you show the ShellExecute() function call as how you are now using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, now it seems to work just fine with the unc path.

Answer (score 2):

I initially tried this approach, but found it caused problems:

- When the presentation was used from a laptop not connected to the network.
- If the user did not have access to the UNC.
- If the flash file was renamed, moved or deleted.

I found a better approach was to embed the file into the Powerpoint file.

It can be done as follows using Office XP, Powerpoint

From the **'View'** menu select **'Toolbars'** and tick the **'Control Toolbox'**

On the **'Control Toolbox'** toolbar click on the **'More controls'** icon

A list of controls will be displayed. Scroll down until you find the **'Shockwave Flash Object'** and then click on it.

This should change your cursor to a crosshair. Move to the area on the slide where you want to inset the **'Shockwave Flash Object'**.
Left click, hold and drag to create a box of the required size.

Next right click on the control you have just inserted and select **'Properties'**.

Set the following properties

```
* Autoload = True
* EmbedMovie = True
* Enabled = True
* Loop = True
* Playing = True
* Visible = True
* Movie = c:\flash.swf (Change this to the location of your .swf file)
```

Close the 'Properties' control

Save the file.

Close the file.

Reopen the file.

The .swf file should start playing automatically when you reach the slide during the slide show.

I found it usefull to include controls (pause/play, time line) in the .swf file

Comment: i have tried something like this a few years back. i found that there were some problems with the interplay between PowerPoint and Flash. Sometimes the flash just would not play. Sometimes it would. It was the sort of bug that I was never able to consistently reproduce it. Maybe it would works now.

Answer (score 0):

UNC paths start with a *double* back-slash.  Are you doing that, or was that just a typo in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I've resorted to mapping a drive to the UNC path.

The command line looks something like

subst A: "\\ServerName\SomeDirectory"

Comment: that seems like a reasonable workaround. my only worry is on some systems users are, i think, not allowed the ability to map network drives. i am going to check this out though, it seems like it should work.